# Converting an Expression to CNF (conjunctive normal form)

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

I am trying to convert the following expression to CNF (conjunctive normal form):
$$ (A \wedge B \wedge M) \vee ( \neg F \wedge B).$$

So I apply the distributive law and get:
$$ \neg F \wedge B \vee (A \wedge B \wedge M).$$

Now, I feel I am stuck. How do I proceed?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: You should apply the distributive law. That's not an application of the distributive law.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen am I right so far?

Comment: No, as I said before, that’s not an application of the distributive law.

Comment: Do you know FOIL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the distributive laws as Graham Kemp enunciated to get
$$(A \wedge B \wedge M) \vee (\neg F \wedge B)
= ((A \wedge B \wedge M) \vee \neg F) \wedge ((A \wedge B \wedge M) \vee B)$$

Now from distributivity again,
$$(A \wedge B \wedge M) \vee \neg F 
= (A \vee \neg F) \wedge (B \vee \neg F) \wedge (M \vee \neg F),$$
while absorption, commutativity and associativity yield
$$(A \wedge B \wedge M) \vee B = B,$$
and so we get the expression
$$(A \vee \neg F) \wedge (B \vee \neg F) \wedge (M \vee \neg F) \wedge B.$$

Again, by absorption, 
$$(B \vee \neg F) \wedge B = B,$$
and so the final expression, in CNF is
$$(A \vee \neg F) \wedge (M \vee \neg F) \wedge B.$$

Answer (score 2):

The distributive law is that $\phi\wedge(\psi\vee \rho)\equiv (\phi\wedge\psi)\vee(\phi\wedge\rho)$ and $\phi\vee(\psi\wedge\rho)\equiv (\phi\vee\psi)\wedge(\phi\vee\rho)$.

---

These are equivalences, so $(\phi\wedge\psi)\vee(\phi\wedge\rho)\equiv\phi\wedge(\psi\vee \rho)$ and $(\phi\vee\psi)\wedge(\phi\vee\rho)\equiv\phi\vee(\psi\wedge\rho)$ too.